# Are Entities between two sub-apps in NestJs sharable?

Tags: nestjs, microservices, typeorm, nest

I am very new to NestJS and I am trying to create a project with multiple subapps. The query that I have is, if one entity is present in one sub-app, can we use that same entity in another sub-app of the same project?

This is my project strucutre:

- apps
- subApp1
- entities
  - entityone.ts
- controller, modules and services
- subApp2
- entities
  - entityTWo.ts
- controller, modules and services

I want to use the entity one in subApp2 service. Is it possible? If so, how we can acheive this? Is there any better way to approach this situation where I need to use Entity of one sub app into another.

I tried exporting the Entity from one sub-app and import the Module in another sub app. But I am getting this error:

`Nest cannot export a provider/module that is not a part of the currently processed module (StoreModule). Please verify whether the exported Store is available in this particular context.`

I am not sure, if it was the correct way for this situation, but this solution came into my mind and i tried it.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to specify `entities` for every `module`.

keep them all together apart, so you can use them wherever you want.

Comment: I tried this way but the issue is that I am creating sub-apps. If we only had modules, the solutions that you suggested will work.

I am getting this error if I try this way : 
Nest cannot export a provider/module that is not a part of the currently processed module (BrandModule). Please verify whether the exported Test is available in this particular context.

I have imported it into the Module but still not working.